# Atualizar o front end

Tags: php, javascript, html

No *back end* quando faço submit ele apenas me altera na base de dados e não no *front end*. O que posso fazer?

Este é o meu código para inserir nova informação no *front end*:

```
<?php
include "../../include/definitions.inc.php";
include "$dir_site_admin/include/control.inc.php";
include "campos.inc.php";
include "$dir_site_admin/include/header.inc.php";

/* --------------------------------------- */
/* identificar o campo chave (id)          */
/* --------------------------------------- */
foreach($arrCampos as $campo) {
    if(isset($campo["chave"]) && $campo["chave"] == '1') {
        $campo_chave = $campo["campo"];
    }
}

/* --------------------------------------- */
/* tratar o submit do form                 */
/* --------------------------------------- */
if(isset($_POST['BTN_SUBMIT'])) {

    /* GRAVAR INSERIR */
    if($_POST[$campo_chave] == 0) {
        $id = ins_query($arrLinguas,$arrCampos,$arrCamposLinguas);
        header("Location: index.php?inserido=".$id);

    /* GRAVAR EDITAR */
    } else {
        query_editar($arrLinguas,$arrCampos,$arrCamposLinguas);
        header("Location: index.php?editado=".$_POST[$campo_chave]);
    }
    exit;
}
?>

<h1><?php echo $tpl_legenda; ?></h1>

<?php
/*
INFORMAÇÕES IMPORTANTES:
- Deve inserir os campos que pretender ver no formulário, neste ficheiro.
- Para os campos sem idioma utiliza a função: insere_campo()
- Para os campos com idioma utiliza a função: insere_campo_linguas()
*/

/* --------------------------------------- */
/* tratar do formulário de inserir/editar  */
/* --------------------------------------- */
?>

<form name="formInserir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php insere_campo($arrCampos[$campo_chave]); ?>
<div id="usual1" class="usual">
    <?php 
    separadores_idiomas($arrLinguas);
    $i=0;
    foreach($arrLinguas as $lingua=> $desc_lingua) { 
        $i++;
        ?>
        <div id="tab<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <?php 
        inicio_tabela_inserir();
        insere_campo_linguas($arrCamposLinguas["titulo"],$lingua);
        insere_campo_linguas($arrCamposLinguas["texto"],$lingua);
        fim_tabela_inserir();
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php 
inicio_tabela_inserir();
insere_campo($arrCampos["ficheiro"]);
insere_campo($arrCampos["activo"]);
btn_submit();
fim_tabela_inserir();
?>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#usual1 ul").idTabs(); 
</script>

<?php
include "$dir_site_admin/include/footer.inc.php";
?>
```

Comment: [Back office](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_office) e [front office](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_office) são termos que se referem a outra coisa. Os termos a que você se refere, no desenvolvimento de software, são [front end e back end](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end).

Comment: Se esse código salva no banco, ele funciona. Agora se o que ta banco não aparece, é porque alguma chamada ta errada. Onde está o código da chamada?